# How to Backup of files to clould/offsite where restore is not tool specific?

Tags: backup, restore, cloud

I need to backup my files from my home server to a offsite/cloud location.

Currently I have about 100GB of data.

- The files must be restorable without the tool that made the backup.
  Ex.: If saved somewhere where I can use FTP to get them, or Amazon S3 if I can use another Amazon S3 Explorer program.
- The backup should be scheduled.
- Windows compatible

Also if it is reliable and free it would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudBerry Backup perfectly matches your requirements. You can restore the files without it using any other Amazon S3 tool including the AWS Console, you can schedule backup, it is Windows compatible.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Looks good, I have a Windows Home Server so it looks like a match.

Answer (score 1):

Timeline Cloud is the best solution for your requirements as it backs up to Amazon S3 and it is compatible with Windows.

I did a lot of search to find the most suitable solution as we share the same requirements, definitely recommend it for you.